# difficulty in fetching and displaying data using ng-repeat one inside the other

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am using one ng-repeat in which i'm displaying the questions from the database,
and the second ng-repeat is to fetching the tags with respect to that particular question from the database and displaying it.
it fetches the tags for each question and while displaying in ng-repeat at last it replaces all the tags with any one of the tag

> for example :- question is 1)what is java->for this the tag should be
>   displayed is "java" 2)what is javascript->javascript
>
> my output is:- sometimes like this
>
> 1)what is java->"java" 2)what is javascript->"java"
>
> and sometimes again refreshing
>
> 1)what is java->"javascript" 2)what is javascript->"javascript"
>
> like this i have so many questions and it is displaying one tag for all
>   the questions

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in tagForm.data track by $index">

    <td align="left">
        <div ng-init='tagForm.getTag(key)'
            class=" w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-margin w3-round "
            style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;">
            <br>
            <p ng-repeat="data2 in tagForm.message track by $index">
                <a ng-click="tagForm.getAnswer(key)">Q. {{value}}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
                    class="badge">{{data2}}</span> <br>
            </p>
            <ul ng-repeat="(key2,value2) in tagForm.ans track by $index">
                <li><b ng-if="key==key2">Ans. {{value2}}</b></li>
            </ul>
            <div ng-init='tagForm.getUser(key)'>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Posted
                    by:{{tagForm.user2[$index]}}</b>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="{{$index}}"
                ng-click="count1=count1+1" ng-init="count1=5+($index*3)-5">
                Upvote <span class="badge">{{count1}}</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="{{$index}}"
                ng-click="count=count+1" ng-init="count=1+($index*2)">
                Downvote<span class="badge">{{count}}</span>
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gotoanswer()">Answer
                this question</button>
            <br> <br />
        </div> <br>
    </td>

    <td height=100px><br /></td>

</tr>
```

**controller code**

```
$scope.tagForm.getTag=function(val){        
    $scope.tagForm.message = null;
var data = JSON.stringify($scope.tagForm);
$http.post(URI + "tag/view2/"+val,data).then(function(response) {
    //var string=response.data;
    //var formattedString = string.join("\n");
    //$scope.askForm.message =formattedString;
    $scope.tagForm.message =response.data;
    //alert($scope.tagForm.message);
}, function(response) {
    $scope.tagForm.message = null;
});
```

};

Comment: it would be nice to see what your `ng-repeat` looks like and how are you loading the data

Comment: the problem is in second ng-repeat